# Getting "Unexpected end of JSON input" for using "utf8_decode"

Tags: javascript, php, json, utf-8, domdocument

I have php codes as following. Following part is called during ajax call:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
                    $internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
                    $doc->loadHTML($post['message']);
                    $post['message'] = utf8_decode($doc->saveHTML($doc->documentElement));
                    $post['message'] .= $lang->sprintf($lang->thx_not_paid, newpoints_format_points($mybb->settings['hidecontent_points']), $mybb->post_code, $post['pid']);
```

This doesn't work and I get following error in frontend:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
```

However, if i remove "utf8_decode" in above code, as following:

```
$post['message'] = $doc->saveHTML($doc->documentElement);
```

Then it works well, with one problem that some characters in "$post['message']" become strange like as following:

```
exceptÂ special move andÂ ranged
```

A has become strange character.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Don’t see the point of calling `utf8_decode` here. What character encoding is your data in, what is the character encoding of the target page that is supposed to display this?

Comment: I'd try [`utf8_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) instead of `utf8_decode`

Comment: `thx_not_paid` is one of those unlucky abbreviations that just ask for misinterpretations.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using following instead:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML("<xml encoding=\"utf-8\" />" . $post['message']);
$post['message'] = $dom->saveHTML();
```